# How to split SQL query results into columns based on two WHERE conditions and two calculated COUNT fields?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have the following (simplified) database schema:

```
Persons:

[Id] [Name]
-------------------
1 'Peter'
2 'John'
3 'Anna'

Items:

[Id] [ItemName] [ItemStatus]
-------------------
10 'Cake' 1
20 'Dog' 2

ItemDocuments:

[Id] [ItemId] [DocumentName] [Date]
-------------------
101 10 'CakeDocument1' '2016-01-01 00:00:00'
201 20 'DogDocument1' '2016-02-02 00:00:00'
301 10 'CakeDocument2' '2016-03-03 00:00:00'
401 20 'DogDocument2' '2016-04-04 00:00:00'


DocumentProcessors:

[PersonId] [DocumentId]
-------------------
1 101
1 201
2 301
```

I have also set up an SQL fiddle to play with: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e6082

The relation logic is the following: every Person can work on zero or infinite number of ItemDocuments (many-to-many); each ItemDocument belongs to exactly one Item (one-to-many). Item has status 1 - Active, 2 - Closed

What I need is a report that fulfills the following requirements:

- for each person in Persons table, display count of Items that have ItemDocuments related to this person
- the counts should be split in two columns by ItemStatus
- the query should be filterable by two optional date periods (using two BETWEEN conditions on ItemDocuments.Date field) and the Item counts should also be split into two periods
- if a Person does not have any ItemDocuments assigned, it still should be shown in the results with all count values set to 0
- if a Person has more than one ItemDocument for an Item, the Item still should be counted only once

Essentially, here is how the results should look like if I use both periods to NULL (to read all the data):

```
    [PersonName]    [Active Items for period 1] [Closed Items for period 1] [Active Items for period 2] [Closed Items for period 2]
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    'Peter' 1   1   1   1
    'John'  1   0   1   0
    'Anna'  0   0   0   0
```

While I can create an SQL query for each requirement separately, I have a problem to understand how to combine all of them together into one.

For example, I can split ItemStatus counts in two columns using

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN t.ItemStatus = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS Active, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN t.ItemStatus = 2 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS Closed
```

and I can filter by two periods (with max/min date constants from MS SQL server specification to avoid NULLs for optional period dates) using

```
between coalesce(@start1, '1753-01-01') and coalesce(@end1, '9999-12-31')
between coalesce(@start2, '1753-01-01') and coalesce(@end2, '9999-12-31')
```

but how to combine all of this together, considering also JOINs between tables?

**Is there any technique, `join` or MS SQL Server specific approach to do this in efficient way?**

My first attempt seems to work as required but it looks like ugly subquery duplications multiple times:

```
DECLARE @start1 DATETIME, @start2 DATETIME, @end1 DATETIME, @end2 DATETIME

-- SET @start2 = '2017-01-01'

SELECT 
p.Name,
(SELECT COUNT(1)
    FROM Items i
    WHERE i.ItemStatus = 1 AND EXISTS(
        SELECT 1 
        FROM DocumentProcessors AS dcp
        INNER JOIN ItemDocuments AS idc ON dcp.DocumentId = idc.Id
        WHERE dcp.PersonId = p.Id AND idc.ItemId = i.Id
        AND idc.Date BETWEEN COALESCE(@start1, '1753-01-01') AND COALESCE(@end1, '9999-12-31')
        )
) AS Active1,

(SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM Items i
    WHERE i.ItemStatus = 2 AND EXISTS(
        SELECT 1 
        FROM DocumentProcessors AS dcp
        INNER JOIN ItemDocuments AS idc ON dcp.DocumentId = idc.Id
        WHERE dcp.PersonId = p.Id AND idc.ItemId = i.Id
        AND idc.Date BETWEEN COALESCE(@start1, '1753-01-01') AND COALESCE(@end1, '9999-12-31')
        )
    ) AS Closed1,

(SELECT COUNT(1)
    FROM Items i
    WHERE i.ItemStatus = 1 AND EXISTS(
        SELECT 1 
        FROM DocumentProcessors AS dcp
        INNER JOIN ItemDocuments AS idc ON dcp.DocumentId = idc.Id
        WHERE dcp.PersonId = p.Id AND idc.ItemId = i.Id
        AND idc.Date BETWEEN COALESCE(@start2, '1753-01-01') AND COALESCE(@end2, '9999-12-31')
        )
) AS Active2,

(SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM Items i
    WHERE i.ItemStatus = 2 AND EXISTS(
        SELECT 1 
        FROM DocumentProcessors AS dcp
        INNER JOIN ItemDocuments AS idc ON dcp.DocumentId = idc.Id
        WHERE dcp.PersonId = p.Id AND idc.ItemId = i.Id
        AND idc.Date BETWEEN COALESCE(@start2, '1753-01-01') AND COALESCE(@end2, '9999-12-31')
        )
    ) AS Closed2

FROM Persons p
```

Comment: That has all a good question should have, sample data (even a fiddle!), own effort, expected output, clear explanation (allthough it's still hard to grok)... Voted it up

Comment: I tried to avoid your *ugly sub-query duplications* by using a CTE...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not absolutely sure if I really got what you want, but you might try this

```
WITH AllData AS
(
    SELECT p.Id AS PersonId
          ,p.Name AS Person
          ,id.Date AS DocDate
          ,id.DocumentName AS DocName
          ,i.ItemName AS ItemName
          ,i.ItemStatus AS ItemStatus
          ,CASE WHEN id.Date BETWEEN COALESCE(@start1, '1753-01-01') AND COALESCE(@end1, '9999-12-31') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS InPeriod1  
          ,CASE WHEN id.Date BETWEEN COALESCE(@start2, '1753-01-01') AND COALESCE(@end2, '9999-12-31') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS InPeriod2
    FROM Persons AS p
    LEFT JOIN DocumentProcessors AS dp ON p.Id=dp.PersonId
    LEFT JOIN ItemDocuments AS id ON dp.DocumentId=id.Id
    LEFT JOIN Items AS i ON id.ItemId=i.Id
)
SELECT PersonID 
      ,Person
      ,COUNT(CASE WHEN ItemStatus = 1 AND InPeriod1 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS ActiveIn1
      ,COUNT(CASE WHEN ItemStatus = 2 AND InPeriod1 = 1  THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS ClosedIn1
      ,COUNT(CASE WHEN ItemStatus = 1 AND InPeriod2 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS ActiveIn2
      ,COUNT(CASE WHEN ItemStatus = 2 AND InPeriod2 = 1  THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS ClosedIn2
FROM AllData
GROUP BY PersonID,Person
```

Comment: Thanks, it almost works. Just one issue - currently it counts documents but I need Item count. I mean - if an Item has multiple ItemDocuments assigned for a Person, this item still should be counted only once per period per Active/Closed. I guess, more deep grouping / CTE will be required for this, and maybe some SUM instead of COUNT.

Comment: Try to reduce the columns *within* the CTE to the columns really needed (no `DocName` or `DocDate` and change the CTE to `SELECT DISTINCT`. Should be enough...

Comment: Ok, I just tried modifying your CTE and finally got it working.

Comment: @JustAMartin, great, glad to here this! Happy Coding!